# Python3 прогнать все свойства класса через функцию

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не знаю как правильно назвать одним словом то, чего я хочу.
В общем есть класс `Event`:

```
class Event:
    def __init__(self, name: str, link: str, start_date: str, finish_date: str, format: str, weight: str):
        self.name = name
        self.link = link
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.finish_date = finish_date
        self.format = format
        self.weight = weight
        self.markdown_beautify()

    def __iter__(self):
        yield 'name', self.name
        yield 'link', self.link
        yield 'start_date', self.start_date
        yield 'finish_date', self.finish_date
        yield 'format', self.format
        yield 'weight', self.weight
```

И хотелось бы прогнать все переменные в классе прогнать через метод.
Что-то в стиле:

```
def markdown_beautify(self):
    for x in self:
        x = markdown_decoration.quote(x)
```

Как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: Добавить все атрибуты класса в список и пройтись по списку?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, слишком некрасиво. Должно же быть прям каефное решение

Comment: @icYFTL Согласен, зачем делать то, что уже есть —  `dir` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example:

```
class Object():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = 1234
        self.attr = 100
    def go(self):
        for x in filter(lambda el: not el.startswith('__') and not callable(getattr(self, el)), dir(self)):
            setattr(self, x, getattr(self, x)+1)

object = Object()
print(object.attr, object.attr1)
object.go()
print(object.attr, object.attr1)
```

Comment: Из-за того, что решение слегка компликейтед, а еще вы объявили на меня крестовый поход.

Comment: `eval(i)` как минимум небезопасен)

Comment: Нормально,  куда уж проще?

Comment: @icYFTL `eval(i)` в данном контексте безопаен т.к. туда попадают четка ваши элементы.

Comment: Разберусь, подумаю и поставлю как решение. А может кто лучше предложит?)

Comment: @icYFTL ну можно же eval убрать чтоб людей не пугать.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, не работает. https://pastebin.com/Rq0sKjXm

Comment: @icYFTL edited. все вот так будет работать!

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, украли идею с мапом! XD

Comment: @icYFTL Но ответ-то  назад примите , так то точно работает.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, и снова мимо. У вас во-первых не работает код, что я и поправил здесь -> `https://pastebin.com/CwejixbE`. Во вторых в `eval('self.'+x)` кладется не ссылка, а копия.

Comment: @icYFTL Ес! Написал рабочий пример (см ответ)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, во, теперь работает. Чет протупил с `setattr`. Большое спасибо!

Comment: @icYFTL Я тоже ступил. Мне аж самому интересно стало ;)

Answer (score 3):

Решил докинуть более красивое решение:

```
class lol:
    def __init__(self):
        self.kek = 'lolo'
        self.rofl = 'kek'
        self.kekrofl = 1
        self.ok = False

test = lol()
for var in vars(list(test)):
    setattr(test, var, 'AZAZA')

print(vars(test))  # Everything is AZAZA
```

Comment: Лучше не использовать подчеркивание как имя переменной, значение которой потом как-то используется.